# Converting djangos object.values dict into native datatype?

Tags: django

I'm trying to get specific fields from my database using the `object.values()` attribute, as such:

```
stocks = Stock.objects.values("ticker", "stock", "exchange__exchange_code", "earnings_yield", "roic")
```

The reason I'm not using `Stock.objects.filter()...` is because I only need a subset of the fields, and as far as I know, `values()` is the way to go.

`stocks[0]` returns this:

```
{
 'ticker': 'ATRLJ-B', 
 'stock': 'Atrium Ljungberg AB (publ)', 
 'exchange__exchange_code': 'ST', 
 'earnings_yield': Decimal('0.0250'), 'roic': Decimal('0.0200')
}
```

How do I get `earnings_yield` and `roic` as regular floats? E.g, proper JSON formatted

I tried

```
    clean = json.dumps(list(stocks), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    stocks = json.loads(clean)
```

But that returns the decimals as strings, not decimals

Comment: are earnings_yield and roic decimal field in models?

Comment: A decimal is converted to a string to preserve the value, since floats can have *rounding* errors.

Comment: Furthermore usually using `.values(...)` is not a good idea since it "erodes" the model layer. Usually a serializer is used to convert these to JSON/XML/CSV/...

Comment: What would the serializer look like? Any pointers

Comment: And how do I get specific values without using `values()`? My `Stock` model has more fields than I need for this specific task

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with [`ExpressionWrapper`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper), use [`FloatField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField) as output field and store it to another field name.

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, F, ExpressionWrapper

Stock.objects.annotate(
  earnings_yield_float=ExpressionWrapper(
    F('earnings_yield'),
    output_field=FloatField()
  ),
  roic_float=ExpressionWrapper(
    F('roic'),
    output_field=FloatField()
  )
).values(
    'ticker',
    'stock',
    'exchange__exchange_code',
    'earnings_yield_float',
    'roic_float'
)
```

> But, bassed on your case, I'll recomend you to use https://www.django-rest-framework.org instead. By using this, your Stock data will be converted as JSON format when you call `serializer.data` *(like below example)*:

For example in your `serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from yourapp.models import Stock


class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ('ticker', 'stock', 'exchange__exchange_code', 
                  'earnings_yield', 'roic')
```

Then in your `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.response import Response
from yourapp.models import Stock


class StockView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(...)

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = StockSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

Meanwhile, `StockSerializer(queryset, many=True).data` will return `OrderDict`, but for a single object it will return as JSON output.

The other way, if you want to dealing with exact JSON output at all, you can use default [`rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#jsonrenderer).

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from yourapp.serializers import StockSerializer
from yourapp.models import Stock

queryset = Stock.objects.all()
serializer = StockSerializer(queryset, many=True)
data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)  # b'[{"id":1, "ticker": ...}]

# the to proces that data you can use the json module
import json
json.loads(data)  # [{'id': 1, 'ticker': ...}]
```

Comment: I was expecting something like this - however. The JSON itself is used by another function inside my django project, so its not directly exposed as an endpoint in the "traditional" way. 

For instance, how would I call this `StockView` from the shell?

Comment: @erikvm meanwhile to test in your shell, you can directly call that `StockSerializer`, for example is like this https://pastebin.com/BwvmdAix

Comment: `serializer.data` returns an OrderedDict, no?

Comment: @erikvm if you use `many=True` => yes, you can [learn more here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#working-with-serializers). But, if you need to exact as JSON output, you can use `JSONRenderer`, I have updated it to my answer.